# Android: Multiple search mode

Tags: android, searchview

I have the search interface like this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html

On the left apears the app logo, but I want a options to select ( like google search application ).

In http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/search-%E2%80%93-main-menu we can read:

> … and the search bar appears at the top of the screen. On the left the app-logo is displayed. (When multiple search modes are supported, the app logo is replaced by an icon for the corresponding and selected search mode, together with an indicator)

So... how can I add multipe search mode?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **not possible**. The website suggests wrong.

What you can do is enable the Quick Search Bar widget for your app as well. There you can have multiple search modes for your app (each will be sent to a different activity handling the search). Like so: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/search/label/Quick%20Search%20Box and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/searchable-config.html#searchable-element

Comment: Thank you for your answer... may be I need to do the search box manually :(

Comment: You can still do different searches in your app, but you have to do them in different activities. It's hard to come up with a usecase where you'd need to use multiple in one activity.

Comment: I want to search something in two different webs and I want the multiple search to leave the user the option to select in witch web search.